# ¿Como alinear diferentes fprintf en c?

Tags: c, printf

**Asi debería ser**

[image]

**Asi me queda a mi**

[image]

Como dice en la primera imagen, tienen que estar alineados pero no quedan asi

```
fprintf (stdout, ("\nAltura: %9.0f", altura);
fprintf (stdout, ("\nBase: %9.0f", base);
```

Comment: Preguntas del tipo: *Esta es mi tarea, como la hago?* no son bien recividas. Aqui no hacemos tareas de gratis. Se espera que demuestres un [poco esfuerzo de tu parte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4884/cuanto-esfuerzo-se-espera-de-los-usuarios-de-stack-overflow?cb=1)

Comment: esfuerzo es que llevo 1h con el mismo problema y lo he acabado resolviendo yo, no entiendo a que viene el reproche

Comment: Te felicito por resolver tu problema. Si lees lo que esta en el link vas a ver ***a que viene el reproche***. No es por ser mal educado, es que si quieres que te hagan la tarea este no es el lugar. Y si quieres ayuda con lo que haces, muestras que es lo que haces.

Comment: Una foto con el resultado que debería ser, otra foto con como me queda a mi y tambien escribi como era el codigo ya que al parecer subir una foto de eso no deja. Además de no haber ninguna otra pregunta como esta. También respondí a la respuesta que me pusieron con comentarios sobre el proceso de como solucioné el problema

Comment: Te recomiendo agregar el **codigo completo** en la pregunta, eso denota lo que has intentado hasta ahora..

Answer (score -1):

Usa un tabulador (\t), de esta forma para poder alinear los valores:

```
fprintf (stdout, "\nAltura:\t%9.0f", altura);
fprintf (stdout, "\nBase:\t%9.0f", base);
fprintf (stdout, "\nArea:\t%9.0f", area);
```

Tendrías por ejemplo una salida:

```
Altura:        45 cm                                                                                                                   
Base:           2 cm                                                                                                                   
Area:  45.00 cm x cm
```

Comment: lo que hice ahora es cambiar el valor de %9 y ajustarlo a la diferencia de caracteres de las palabras. Como base y area miden lo mismo pues %9, altura %7 y perimetro %3

Comment: aunque sigue estando mal porque si en la altura son dos caracteres y en la base 1 ya no estan alineados, creo que no se puede hacer lo que pide mi profesor para cualquier valor

Comment: bueno si que vale si pones un valor de %[numero] lo suficiente grande para que deje suficiente espacio, cuando se queda corto es cuando no se alinean